# Ruby on rails..radio button issue

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

```
    <CENTER><h4><%=question.quest %> </h4></CENTER>
    <tr><center><%= f.label "option1" %></center></tr>
    <tr><center><%= f.radio_button :answer,"1" %></center></tr>

    <td><center><%= f.label "option2" %></td>
    <td><%= f.radio_button :answer,"2" %></center></td>

    <tr><center><%= f.label "option3" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :answer,"3" %></center></tr>

    <tr><center><%= f.label "option4" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :answer,"4" %></center></tr>

    <tr><center><%= f.label "option5" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :answer,"5" %></center></tr>
    <% end %>
     <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <CENTER><% question.option1.split(" ").each do |option1| %>
    <radio name="question_<%=question.id%>" value="" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp><%=option1 %> </radio>

<CENTER><% question.option2.split(" ").each do |option2| %>
    <radio name="question_<%=question.id%>" value="" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp><%=option2 %> </radio>

<CENTER><% question.option3.split(" ").each do |option3| %>
    <radio name="question_<%=question.id%>" value="" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp><%=option3 %> </radio>

<CENTER><% question.option4.split(" ").each do |option4| %>
    <radio name="question_<%=question.id%>" value="" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp><%=option4 %> </radio>


<CENTER><% question.option5.split(" ").each do |option5| %>
    <radio name="question_<%=question.id%>" value="" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp><%=option5 %> </radio>

<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>


<center><p><%= f.button :submit%></p></center>
```

Thank you for completing these questions!

My issue is there are 2 questions with 5 options..In 1st question i will click radio button and when i click the second question radio button means the 1st question radio button is going..

Comment: Just check radio button names using `code inspect` feature of any web browser.

Comment: Hello Everyone,

              I have an android application which contains registration form.
In that i will enter all the details and i will click on submit button.
By using api the given details should be saved in database.
How can i write Api's in ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but radio_button description in RoR guide say that:

> "1.3.2 Radio Buttons
>
> Radio buttons, while similar to checkboxes, are controls that specify a set of options in which they are mutually exclusive (i.e., the user can only pick one):"

In this case user can select only one option. 
Maybe check_box fields will be solution in this case?

> please check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: if there is one survey form..in that survey form there will be multiple questions and there will be options..in my case only one question answer is saving..the other question answers is not saving..and the radio button is checked only one question..it is not working for multiple questions...so i want a solution..